# Laravel Fortify Routes not Registering

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-fortify

I'm using PHP 8.2.0, Laravel 10.9.0, Inertia 1.0.6 and Vue 3.2.47. I've uncommented `Features::resetPasswords()` from `config/fortify.php`, and I've added `Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView(function() { return Inertia::render('Fortify/ForgotPassword'); });` to the `FortifyServiceProvider`, but even after runnning `artisan route:clear` and `artisan cache:clear`, the route list does not show `/forgot-password`. Am I missing something with how to set this up? The register, login, and confirm password views I added earlier all work fine and with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `FortifyServiceProvider` registered in your `config/app.php`?

[Link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify#the-fortify-service-provider)

Comment: Yep, it's in there already.